Scroll function for CTkScrollableFrame (Python)
I'm trying to find a function that lets me automatically scroll to the bottom in a ctk.CTkScrollableFrame. I couldn't find anything besides creating a canvas and adding a scrollbar but I feel like there should be a function to directly access the scrollbar in the CTkScrollableFrame?
The App
Im looking for something like this:
            self.chat_frame = ctk.CTkScrollableFrame(self.frame, height=400)
            self.chat_frame.pack(pady=12, padx=10, fill="x")

            #function that adds new messages [...]

            self.chat_frame.scroll_to_bottom() # <---the function I'm looking for


Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

If you look into the source code of CTkScrollableFrame and understand its structure, you can do what you want as below:
# make sure all updates are handled
self.chat_frame.update_idletasks()
# move the view port of the *parent canvas* to the bottom of *scrollregion*
self.chat_frame._parent_canvas.yview_moveto(1.0)

